# Cleaning a text with Regular expression

Tags: java, regex, string

I am reading a text file and I want to find correct tokens of the text. But I have problem with dot at the end of the sentences.My code is the following code and query means input string:

```
    query = query.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\s0-9-_/.]", "");
    query = query.replaceAll("\t", " ");
    query = query.replaceAll("\r", " ");
    query = query.replaceAll("\n", " ");
    StringTokenizer words = new StringTokenizer(query, " ");    
    while(tokens.hasMoreTokens()){
            String str=tokens.nextToken();
            String regex = "\\d+.\\d+";
            if(!str.matches(regex)) *<- second problem*
               System.out.println(str);
```

For example; the Input text is the following line

```
THE WORLD OF UNIQUE VENDING CARTS. fy_lkaris@yahoo.com  www.ubc_lib?9867.come/homepage 876454 9890-9999-9099.
```

I want the following string as output

```
THE WORLD OF UNIQUE VENDING CARTS
fy_lkaris@yahoo.com
www.ubc_lib?9867.come/homepage
9890-9999-9099
```

But my real out put has dot at the end of first and last line of output.
I can not delete dot (.) since it delete from every place.

```
THE
WORLD
OF
UNIQUE
VENDING
CARTS.ff_lashkariyahoo.com   *<-problem*
www.unb_lib9867.come/homepage
9890-9999-9099.              *<-problem*
```

Also I want to delete only numbers like 4,764,90.900 not 76-098-098 and I could not find any better than useing **match** function .Is there any way to solve this problem too.

Could you please help me?

Comment: Well, you've already specified when you want to delete the dots (at the end/ before a space), so I'd start from there. So, remove it from the removeAll character class for starters.

Comment: @keyser if I remove dot  `query.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\s0-9-_/.]", "")` from this part then the string _yahoo.com_ is changed to _yahoocom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way for solving my problems. I changed my code to the following code and it works.

```
query = query.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\s0-9-_/.@]", "");
query = query.replaceAll("\t", " ");
query = query.replaceAll("\r", " ");
query = query.replaceAll("\n", " ");
StringTokenizer words = new StringTokenizer(query, " ");    
while(tokens.hasMoreTokens()){
        String str=tokens.nextToken();
        str = str.replaceAll("\\.\\B" , " "); *<-new line*
        String regex = "\\d+.\\d+";
        if(!str.matches(regex)) *<- second problem*
           System.out.println(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is presence of **unescaped hyphen in the middle of character class**. A hyphen can be unescaped only when it is placed at start or end position inside character class.

Use this:

```
query = query.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\s0-9_/.-]", "");
```

When hyphen comes in the middle it acts **as range**. In your case it creating a range between digit 9 (ASCII: 57) and underscore (ASCII: 95).

Comment: I did not see any different between your regular expression and my. Could you specify the different.

Comment: The difference is already explained. Look at the last character of the class, the hyphen: `-`

Comment: @user3487667: You had hyphen between `9` and `_` and I have `-` at the the end before `]`

Comment: @anubhava I still have my problems.what should it change ?

Comment: Your regex rules are not clear to me. When should dot to be removed when it should not.

Comment: @anubhava when after dot we have space we need to remove it such as `CARTS.` and `9890-9999-9099.` and not remove when  `yahoo.com`